# I Program OpenGL in Qt 5 have no image

Tags: qt, opengl

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QMatrix4x4>
class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~GLWidget();
protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    virtual void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    GLuint compileShaders();
private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram *program;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject vao;
    QOpenGLBuffer vbo;
    static const char *vshader_source;
    static const char *fshader_source;
};


#endif // GLWIDGET_H

#include "glwidget.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGLFormat>

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{

}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    GLfloat color[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat points[] = {1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,
                        0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,
                        1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0};
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

    program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
    program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vshader_source);
    program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fshader_source);
    program->bindAttributeLocation("vertex", 0);
    program->link();
    assert(program->bind());

    vao.create();
    //vao.bind();
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&vao);
    vbo.create();
    vbo.bind();
    vbo.allocate(points, sizeof(points));

    vbo.bind();
    QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
    f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    f->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    vbo.release();

    program->release();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&vao);
    program->bind();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    program->release();
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}

//GLuint GLWidget::compileShaders()
//{
//    GLint status;
//    GLchar log[1024];
//    vshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
//    glShaderSource(vshader, 1, vshader_source, NULL);
//    glCompileShader(vshader);
//    glGetShaderiv(vshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
//    glGetShaderInfoLog(vshader, 1024, NULL, log);
//    qDebug()<<log;
//    assert(status == GL_TRUE);

//    fshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
//    glShaderSource(fshader, 1, fshader_source, NULL);
//    glCompileShader(fshader);
//    glGetShaderiv(fshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
//    glGetShaderInfoLog(fshader, 1024, NULL, log);
//    qDebug()<<log;
//    assert(status == GL_TRUE);

//    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
//    glAttachShader(program, vshader);
//    glAttachShader(program, fshader);
//    glLinkProgram(program);
//    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
//    assert(status == GL_TRUE);

//    glDeleteShader(vshader);
//    glDeleteShader(fshader);

//    return program;
//}


const char *GLWidget::vshader_source =
    "attribute vec4 vertex;\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "gl_Position = gl_Vertex;\n"
    "}\n";

const char *GLWidget::fshader_source =
    "void main(){                             \n"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0); \n"
    "}                                        \n";
```

This is my Qt code, I have tried many times to change shader and other code, but all the code is failed and have no image. I have no idea, there is any one help me?
And when I meet this problem at later, how can I find the reason why this program doesn't work, because it doesn't report any error and there is little information of OpenGL Program in Qt5.

Ok,I have found the error in the code which is that"
f->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
".
the 3 must change to 4.
But I still want to know how to learn opengl on qt5.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I have found the error in the code which is that

```
// ...
vbo.bind();
QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
f->glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
vbo.release();.
// ...

void glVertexAttribPointer( GLuint index,
GLint size,
GLenum type,
GLboolean normalized,
GLsizei stride,
const GLvoid * pointer);
```

the 3 in **glVertexAttribPointer** method must change to 4.

Because this pecifies the number of components per generic vertex attribute. Must be 1, 2, 3, 4. Additionally, the symbolic constant GL_BGRA is accepted by glVertexAttribPointer. The initial value is 4.